# How do i carry variables across pages?

Tags: javascript, html, input, window

I want to have a variable that I can access across pages. I have tried using window.(variable).document but it hasn't worked for me. Is there a way I can send information from one tab to another? I don't prefer local storage stuff but if it's the only way then I can deal with it.
Here's what i have right now

```
<html>
    <body>
    <button onclick="open()">copy text</button>
    <button onclick="run()">open page</button>
<script>
function run() {
//make the window (works)
var w = window.open("", "Game", "width=2000,height=1000");
//make an input in the window (works)
 w.document.write("<input id='e'>");
}
function run() {
//get the text from the other window (doesn't work)
var copy = w.document.getElementById("e");
//write the output (works, has nothing to output)
document.write(copy);
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also use cookies but localStorage allows much more spaces, and they aren't sent back to servers when you request pages.

Comment: you can send value by `postMessage` or `urlStringParameter`, if one of these solutions is okay for you, I make one example as a answer.